# How to display two sections in same block?

Tags: html, css

```css
#summary {
  width:200px;
}

#summary div {
  font-size:0.875em;
  margin-top:10px; 
}
.lv2 {
    margin-left:15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="summary">
      <div class="book-title lv1">IntroductionIntroductionIntroduction</div>
      <div class="book-title lv1">1. AAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAA</div>
      <div class="book-title lv1">2 BBBBBBBBBB BBBBBBBB BBBBBBBBBBBB</div>
      <div class="book-title lv2">2.1. bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbbb</div>
    </div>
```

What can I do to make second line start under tile not number(not using ol and li)?
Which mean the number and title may be two different block, maybe?

Comment: Use `ol` & `li` for this.

Comment: I know I can use ol and li, however, I need to let users type the number by theyself.

Comment: can you use `<br />`

Comment: if i use br tag, the number and title will be two different line.what i want is,when title is too long,it will start at second line,and i need second line start under first word of first line not start  under number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You WILL need to separate them then.

```
<div class="book-title lv2">
<div class="col-1">2.1. </div>
<div class="col-2">bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbbb</div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xwddpp